# Slow/unresponsive animation with jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scroll, jquery-animate

I am writing a small jQuery function and I seem to be having trouble.

What I am trying to do here is when the user scrolls down the page by 90px, a div tag should animate down (from top:-50px to top:0), and vice-versa when they scroll back to the top of the page.

The problem I am having is that the animation seems to be very slow and unresponsive at times.  I test in 3 different browsers and different computers but I am having no joy.

Here is my code:

```
    // Show div
    var scrollValue = "90";

    // Animate functions
    var showHead = function (){
$(".element").animate({top: "0"}, 250);
}
var hideHead = function (){
$(".element").animate({top: "-50px"}, 250);
}

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > scrollValue) {
            showHead();
        } else {
            hideHead();
        }
    });
```

The .element properties:

```
.element { positoin:fixed; top:-50px; }
```

Could anyone figure out why my code the hide/showHead functions are so sloppy?

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: Please use a descriptive and comprehensive title in your questions. This is not a bug spotting contest

Comment: Care to make a jsfiddle.net? I'm not sure how you're styling `.element`, but that may have something to do with it?

Comment: Having said that, have you tried using `.stop()` as in `$(".element").stop().animate({ ... })`?

Comment: Perhaps you should not enqueue an animation each time a scroll event is received

Comment: what is your `$(".element")` `position` ?

Comment: Try adding a .stop() before the call to animate.

Comment: @Alexander you nailed it! Go answer and I will accept the answer!

Comment: @PeterStuart, perfect, there you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scroll` event is triggered several times and even though it is rate-limited it keeps being a rather intensive operation. Actually, you may be queuing several animations and the `fx` stack may be growing very quickly.

One possibility you can try is stopping all previous animations before triggering a new one. You can do this by using [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

```
$(".element").stop().animate({top: "0"}, 250);
```

The `.stop()` function also provides some other options which you can use to tweak it even more.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (window.scrollY > scrollValue) {
        showHead();
    } else {
        hideHead();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`scroll` events occurred many time durring user scrolling.

You need to check if your animation is in progress before starting the animation again.

Try this :

```
// Show div
var scrollValue = "90";
var inProgress = false;

// Animate functions
var showHead = function () {
    if(inProgress)
        return false;

    //Animate only if the animation is not in progress
    inProgress = true;

    $(".element").animate({
        top: "0"
    },250,function(){
        inProgress = false; //Reset when animation is done
    });
}
var hideHead = function () {
    if(inProgress)
        return false;

    //Animate only if the animation is not in progress
    inProgress = true;

    $(".element").animate({
        top: "-50px"
    }, 250,function(){
        inProgress = false; //Reset when animation is done
    });
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > scrollValue) {
        showHead();
    } else {
        hideHead();
    }
});
```

Comment: No need to re-invent the wheel, jQuery provides the [`:animated`](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) selector.

Answer (score 1):

try using queue: false and as Alexander said use `.stop()`

here jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hwbPz/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `position:fixed` (or some other sort of styling making the bar visible when necessary):

```
var scrollheight = 90;

var $el = $('.element');
function showHead(){
    $el.stop().animate({
        top: '0px'
    }, 250);
}
function hideHead(){
    $el.stop().animate({
        top: '-50px'
    }, 250);
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > scrollheight){
        showHead();
    }else{
        hideHead();
    }
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/L4LfL/